# Understanding the definition of subcover

Tags: metric-spaces

> A collection $\xi = \{ G_a  :  a \in \Lambda\}$ of subsets of $X$ is said to be cover of $X$ if union of $G_{a \in \Lambda}$ equals to $X$.

A subclass $\xi'$ of a cover $\xi$ is said to be subcover of $\xi'$ if itself covers X.

what does subclass in the definition here means?

Comment: In this context it refers to a subset of the collection of subsets of $X$ which cover $X$, unless you wanted a more in depth explanation of a subclass?

Comment: subclass means subset of the collection.  I think they are simply trying to avoid overusing the word "set" when they are referring to a set of sets.  It's hard on the poor students.

Comment: okey thanks got it

Comment: Sorry , but you are not allowed to comment on quality of students. The vote is for the answer not for the comment "poor students".